# Privacy / Security Splash Screen - detect system alerts and avoid showing privacy screen in those cases

Tags: ios, splash-screen

Currently, I have a privacy screen implemented in applicationWillResignActive - however, when system alerts are shown (location, photos, notification permissions, even hyperlinks to maps etc) it is showing the privacy screen. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Is it not clear what you are asking, this question will probably be closed soon in its current state. What is your problem, what are you trying to achieve? Please include some code that you think contains the problem.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place to ask for help with your code. You’re supposed to show the code you have an issue with and receive help with it. It isn’t a place for general questions or “how do I do this?” type questions. You didn’t read the site requirements for an acceptable question before posting. This site is for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not make you "privacy" screen show in the `applicationWillResignActive:` but in the `applicationDidEnterBackground:`.

This does mean then when you enter the app switcher from your app it will not show, but once you have exited your app it will.

Comment: I tried that (per many other recommendations and apple guidelines) but then it only shows when the app is minimized to home screen. - thus defeating the purpose. The idea is to have privacy when in the app switcher.

Comment: It will have the privacy in the app switcher but only once you app has been backgrounded. If you want it when every the user enters the appswitched you will have to learn to life with the fact that any permissions alert will also tigger it.